# how to duplicate a pattern?

Tags: c, algorithm, for-loop

I wanted to make a program that make a triangle pattern and also make an input that let it duplicate but I'm still new to programming and I didn't find any solution to this.

I wanted to make it like this.
**input example:**
`2 3`
then the output looks like:

```
   *
  **
 ***
   *
  **
 ***
```

this is my current code.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
  
int main()  
{  

//the triangle code
    int n,m=1;  
    scanf("%d",&n);  
    for(int i=n;i>=1;i--)  
    {  
        for(int j=1;j<=i-1;j++)  
        {  
          printf(" ");  
        }  
        for(int k=1;k<=m;k++)  
        {  
            printf("*");  
        }  
        printf("\n");  
        m++;  
    }
```

Comment: Have you learned to write your own functions other than `main()` yet?  If so, you should write the code for generating the triangle in a function that is called from `main()`.  You then arrange to loop in the `main()` function, calling the printing function as many times as you need the output to repeat.

Comment: I just started learning loops recently. and I'm planning to learn array after this . So I'll try my best to learn how to write my own functions after!

Comment: If you don't know functions yet, then you simply need to wrap a loop around your outer `for` loop to repeat the code as often as you want (it looks like you want it twice from your example).  `for (int r = 0; r < 2; r++) { …your existing for loop(s)… }` (where `r` is 'repeat count'; there wouldn't be any harm in using a longer name, such as `rep_cnt` or `rep_count` or even `repeat_count` — though I find that too wordy).  If you need to prompt the user for the number of repeats, do so outside the loops, and replace `2` with the validated value that the user entered (positive and less than 20?).

Answer (score 0):

Just put an other loop around it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int iterations, n, m;
    scanf("%d %d", &iterations, &n);
    for (int k=0; k<iterations; k++) {
        m = 1;
        for(int i=n; i>=1; i--) {
            for(int j=1; j<=i-1; j++) {
                printf(" ");
            }
            for(int j=1; j<=m; j++) {
                printf("*");
            }
            printf("\n");
            m++;
        }
    }
}
```

And if you know what a function does:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void make_tri(int size) {
    for(int i=size-1; i>=0; i--) {
        for(int j=1; j<=i; j++) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for(int j=1; j<=size-i; j++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int iterations, n;
    printf("please enter two numbers: ");
    if (scanf("%d %d", &iterations, &n) != 2) {
        printf("incorrect input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<iterations; i++) {
        make_tri(n);
    }
}
```

You don't need the variable `m`, since you are already counting with `i`. Also please give your variables more descriptive names in the future. This will help with more complex problems.